# Making a bool stay either true or false in Django

Tags: python, django, email, boolean

In my code, I email the user asking whether they want to confirm or deny the order by sending them two links (make the bool false or true). The only problem is, they can continually change the bool by clicking true then false true then false, etc. I would like it to where if they click the true link, they can't go back and make it false.

Here's the code in views.py:

```
def confirm(request, itemnum):
        item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
        item.confirmed = True
        item.save()
        confirm_title = 'Purchase Order %s Confirmed' % item.product
        send_mail(confirm_title, 'Check the Product Order System to see the updated list.', 'MyEmail@gmail.com',['YourEmail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponse('Product  %s  confirmed' % item.product )

def deny(request, itemnum):
        item = get_object_or_404 (PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
        item.confirmed = False
        item.save()
        deny_title = 'Purchase Order %s Denied' % item.product
        send_mail(deny_title, 'Check the Product Order System to see the updated list.', 'MyEmail.com', ['YourEmail@gmail.com'], fail_silently = False)
        return HttpResponse('Product  %s denied' % item.product)
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent them from going back, or prevent them from changing the bool? Or are you fine with either?

Comment: I want the person I emailed with the link to be able to either confirm or deny it ONCE. after they have made it true or false, they can not go back and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Peter's answer is to have two boolean fields, the first being the one you're dealing with now, and the second called `HasResponded`. Then when the user clicks the link, the view does the following:

```
if instance.HasResponded:
    return render(request, 'already-responded.html',)
else:
    instance.HasResponded = True;
    instance.Bool = response
    instance.save()
    return render(request, 'template.html',)
```

Just to give you some choice.

Comment: I apologize I am new to Python. So, would I place this in my views.py with the above code I said? And would the Bool be instance.confirmed for me?

Comment: In the code I wrote, `instance` is the instance of the object you're working on. It's what you wrote as `item` in your code above. And yes, what I wrote as `instance.Bool` is what you called `item.confirmed`. So you'll just need to add the field `HasResponded` or (more appropriately) `has_responded` to your model ('PurchaseOrder'). The sample I gave above should be in your view.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this using a `NullBooleanField`, initialize the value to `None` before confirming or denying, then detect non-`None` values in the confirm and deny views and provide whatever response you want to give on attempts to change the status.  I would probably return a page saying something like "Product %s has already been confirmed" or the like depending on its status, but obviously it depends on your situation.

Other solutions are certainly possible - a foreign key to a Status model could be a good idea if you anticipate getting any more complicated.